# android studio android.support.v4 not found

Tags: android-studio

I have been looking for this for last 4/5 hours, but couldn't solve the mystery. I am trying to migrate my project from Eclipse to Android Studio but have this error. What I have tried after googling is:

1) Add compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1' in dependencies of build.gradle file

2) Close and import again (several times).

Can anybody please show some light before I decide to go back to Eclipse again?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all support repositories and libraries are updated in Android SDK Manager.